# Yii framework gallerymanager extension

Tags: yii, image-gallery, yii-extensions

I'm using the galleymanager extension to create a image gallery. Directory structure is like below,

```
protected
    ...
    modules
    ...
    imgManager
```

Defined the module in config/main.php file as below,

```
'imgManager' => array(
    'import'=>array('imgManager.*','imgManager.components.*'),
    'layout'=>'application.views.layouts.column1',
    'upload_directory'=>'gallery_images',
    'max_file_number' => '10',//max number of files for bulk upload.
    'max_file_size' => '1mb',
),
```

When I'm trying to access the module like, "localhost/site/imgManager". I'm getting the below error,

```
Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "<controller>/imgManager".
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

if imgManager is a seperate module, you should access it like this: localhost/imgManager instead of trying to access it through the controller

Answer (score 0):

ThomasvdBerge is right, you can see a module as a mini application within Yii. For example I would access my admin module like this withing my application:

```
admin/sysMessage/index
```

`<name of module>/<controller>/<action>`

Note: this is with urlmanager enabled, if you don't have that enabled it would be like this:

```
index.php?r=admin/sysMessage/index
```